# Custom button icon duplicates on click

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, font-awesome, fullcalendar-5

Funny problem, but it's been driving me nuts. I have a custom toolbar button containing a FontAwesome icon. Every time I click any of the toolbar buttons ( < > today month week day ) another icon is added to the custom button.

In other words, if click to look at last week, or change from week to month view, I get 2, then 3, then 4, etc. of the icons on the custom button.

I'll try to add a picture to show what I mean. I have tried deleting various configuration options, but nothing so far prevents the extra icons from appearing.

[image: Picture showing extra icons on custom button]

Here's my setup:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  themeSystem: 'standard',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today config',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  slotMinTime: '06:00:00',
  slotMaxTime: '21:00:00',
  navLinks: true,
  selectable: true,
  editable: true,
  dropable: true,
  eventStartEditable: true,
  eventResizableFromStart: true,
  eventDurationEditable: true,
  dayMaxEvents: true,
  eventDisplay: 'block',
  eventConstraint: {
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: '2100-01-01'
  },
  customButtons: {
    config: {
      icon: ' fa fa-cog',
      click: function() {
        window.location = 'calendar_options.html';
      }
    }
  },
```

---

Here is a full example where I have removed all of the unnecessary code. It still shows the same behavior. Code is below.

[https://rstoeber.com/calendar/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSiRu.png)

I assume there is something wrong with how I defined the custom button, but I followed other examples that I found.

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-/BxOvRagtVDn9dJ+JGCtcofNXgQO/CCCVKdMfL115s3gOgQxWaX/tSq5V8dRgsbc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-dPBGbj4Uoy1OOpM4+aRGfAOc0W37JkROT+3uynUgTHZCHZNMHfGXsmmvYTffZjYO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href='lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='lib/main.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      themeSystem: 'standard',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today config',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      customButtons: {
        config: {
          icon: ' fa fa-cog',
          click: function() {
            window.location = 'calendar_options.html';
          }
        }
      },
      events: [
            {
                'id': 9,
                'textColor': '#FFFFFF',
                'backgroundColor': '#AA2217',
                'title': 'Meet Doug at IBM building',
                'start': '2022-04-08 10:00:00',
                'end': '2022-04-08 11:00:00'
            }, {
                'id': 16,
                'textColor': '#FFFFFF',
                'backgroundColor': '#AA2217',
                'title': 'End of week party',
                'start': '2022-04-12 11:00:00',
                'end': '2022-04-12 12:00:00'
            }
      ]

    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Is there any other click handler in your code ?

Comment: I have removed all click handlers and still have the same problem. I will post more example outside of this comment, which is limited to 500 characters.

Comment: Take a look at this thread if you want more informations on handlers https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5449

Comment: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJzdaBw if anyone wants a [mre].

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't happen if you don't use the icon - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNdPYYm, or if you use one of the standard icons - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOoqQZK, so I'd guess the problem relates directly to the use of font-awesome icons which, as far as I can see, is [not explicitly supported](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonIcons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ---UPDATED ANSWER

Inspecting the elements gives you the idea that fullcalendar is using class to show you the icons. It tries to read the icon name you are providing and then add it to a span tag inside the HTML. If you provide the font-awsome icon directly in the icon of the custom button, it will create an SVG for every button the user presses in the window. (the reason I think is hiding behind the js of the Fullcalendar itself)
in this case, you can manually manipulate this by adding extra lines of js to use font-awsome.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    themeSystem: "standard",
    
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today config",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
    },
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    customButtons: {
      config: {
        icon: `cog`,
        click: function () {
          //window.location = "calendar_options.html";
          alert("Hi")
        }
      }
    },
    events: [
      {
        id: 9,
        textColor: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#AA2217",
        title: "Meet Doug at IBM building",
        start: "2022-04-08 10:00:00",
        end: "2022-04-08 11:00:00"
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        textColor: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#AA2217",
        title: "End of week party",
        start: "2022-04-12 11:00:00",
        end: "2022-04-12 12:00:00"
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});


$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".fc-icon-cog").append('<i class="fas fa-cog"></i>');
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
};

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-/BxOvRagtVDn9dJ+JGCtcofNXgQO/CCCVKdMfL115s3gOgQxWaX/tSq5V8dRgsbc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-dPBGbj4Uoy1OOpM4+aRGfAOc0W37JkROT+3uynUgTHZCHZNMHfGXsmmvYTffZjYO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-PL1mKrYeZkM5SsJ5nydN6463HLkV918bgDdYL0I5Z+k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.min.css" integrity="sha256-16PDMvytZTH9heHu9KBPjzrFTaoner60bnABykjNiM0=" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

---

### ---BEFORE UPDATE

As I have researched the documentation and the problem itself, I have noticed that there is an error in this code snippet.

- The stated problem is regarding the use of the font-awsome. As it is explicitly expressed in the documentation, when you are using the standard theme, you have only four icons available to use. As a point of reference, you can refer to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonIcons

Do not hesitate to comment under this post for any follow-ups.

Comment: Removing the space causes the icon to disappear, which isn't going to be helpful - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBpgLLy. Did you test your answer before posting? Also, please don't post runnable snippets which don't actually run...

Comment: `Also, you can try to re-arrange your code to put the declaration of the custom icon first and then the rest of the stuff`...why would that help? The order of the options in a JS object literal has no significance at all. Don't just post random suggestions with no basis or evidence, it's a pointless distraction. If you think you have an answer, test the code first to make sure it actually works as you think it will, and also explain properly _why_ your change would solve the problem.

Comment: `You haven't read the first error at all`...what specifically do you mean? It's unclear. I already, myself, in an [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71915222/custom-button-icon-duplicates-on-click/71937881?noredirect=1#comment127116130_71915222) pointed out that the font-awesome icons aren't fully supported. And now I've pointed out and proved via a demo that your suggestion of removing the space doesn't fix the issue properly...

Comment: ...and I've also pointed out that simply rearranging the order of the options doesn't achieve anything and appears to be just guesswork on your part. That appears to cover everything in your answer. So what exactly do you feel I've missed? I'm happy to be corrected, if you can explain clearly.

Comment: The problem of adding a new icon near the old one will be solved when you remove the space. (point 2) the problem is that the icon won't show in this case. so It could and can be helpful maybe for other contributors, cause we're not alone on this platform.

Comment: I have edited the last point because due to the run I have found out it is not working out

Comment: `The problem of adding a new icon near the old one will be solved when you remove the space`...it won't because it just causes there to be no icon. It doesn't achieve what the OP wants. An answer is supposed to provide a solution.

Comment: Shayan, thanks for the code. I only had a few minutes, but that does seem to work. This solution also feels better than removing the extra icons, as someone else suggested. I'll do more testing after a meeting.

Comment: dear @Robert. You're welcome, please feel free to test it out in your project and tell me if something is not right.

Comment: Dear @Robert have you had the chance to test this out?

Comment: Shayan, yes, it definitely seems to solve the problem with no obvious bad side effects yet.

Comment: @Robert Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found not the solution for your issue but I've got a workaround, add this to your option and it should be fine for the moment:

```
datesSet: function( view, element ) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.fc-config-button svg:not(:first-child)').forEach((e) => {
          e.remove()
        })
      }
```

Just remove the excessive icons xD

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like that, but can't find datesSet in the documentation. Is that documented somewhere? I would still like to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is an actual bug when Font Awesome is used.

Comment: I've found it here https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5449 , it's not in the documentation

Comment: @Robert `datesSet` definitely exists in the documentation, you can find it [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) or from the [main table of contents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) (with help from the magic of Ctrl+F!)

Comment: @Dani `datesSet` is definitely in the documentation...see above comment.